# Issue with heap memory usage in Mule

Tags: mule

I got a mule app but after running it for hours, i can see that the heap memory is increasing until it reaches the limit and the app gets restarted.

I was doing some tests with a Profiler and found that i got a large amount of strings being duplicated (69300).

Why is this happening? should i be using string.intern() ? one of the strings that says it's being duplicated around 3800 times is a string I wasn't even using during testing...

Another string that was being duplicated was a common mule app string which is the: "[app-name].processing.time.monitor"

Is this a Mule bug? I'm using Mule 3.3.2

Any suggestion or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Mule version? Config? Impossible to help without that, but knowing that Mule is used in prod the suspicion is on your app :)

Comment: I'm using Mule 3.3.2. What config do you need? wrapper.conf?

Comment: oh, you mean the mule xml files? (the flow ones?) its an entire project.

Comment: Can you boil it down to a single flow that reproduces the issue?

Comment: thing is that i can't tell where this is happening, the app is really huge, tried looking at the profiler but i can't tell where this is happening :S the objects that are wasting more memory are char[], strings, byte[].

Comment: OK, well, it's hard to tell then without knowing the specifics of your application.

Comment: is the app running embedded or within mule standalone?

Comment: its installed on prod servers and happens the same... just run a simple test by your own, create a simple project, with a flow that contains a few normal and session variables, a choice evaluating one of those variables... a java component that has strings, chars[] or whatever you like... run it and look into the profiler, Mule itself creates thousands and thousands of duplicate strings of native Mule code, and that's only a simple project with 1 flow.... :S

Comment: @DavidDossot run a test as i did and check at the profiler, there are tones of mule duplicated strings and arrays that are created by default, plus the ones of your application... is that normal? what's going on with the garbage collector? having 1,200 of "[appname].processing.time.monitor" isn't a good thing for memory, right? :/ a simple project like this has 6653 duplicated strings, 10106 duplicated arrays, and much more... imagine a real huge project

Comment: You're using 3.3.2 EE right? It's maybe an EE specific issue? Can you try with 3.4.0 CE? Or if you're an EE customer then turn to MuleSoft's support.

Comment: I'm using 3.3.1 CE right now. I'm going to test it out with 3.5.0 CE and let you guys know, this might be a 3.3.1 issue.

Comment: I've run extended load tests on 3.3.1 in the past with no problem. Still, you are having an issue so there must be a difference between our apps or setups. Can you run your tests on 3.4.0 to potentially rule out a bug?

Comment: Looks like i found an error in a class of mine... after disabling it, everything ran better!!! cant believe it... thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue that has been fixed in 3.4.0 CE (and EE releases for earlier Mule versions): https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-5276

Comment: yeah, i've read that too... also in 3.4.0 CE haven't gotten that problem anymore, with the processing string... so you are correct. And now all is working :D thanks everyone